# Browser Memory Consumtion

Tags: firefox, memory, browser

I am developing a Web Application.

I have the feeling, that the browser's memory consumption is higher than it should be with my application. Is there a way or tool by which I can see what parts do consume the memory of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

How about [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)?

"A (code) profiler is a performance analysis tool that, most commonly, measures only the frequency and duration of function calls, but there are other specific types of profilers (**e.g. memory profilers**) in addition to more comprehensive profilers, capable of gathering extensive performance data"

Answer (score 0):

One of the Microsoft utilities (assuming you are using Windows) you can use is LeakDiag (see ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/PSS/Tools/Developer%20Support%20Tools/LeakDiag/).  With LeakDiag you can take 'memory snapshots'of the application.  You can use it as follows:

- Start the application
- Warm up the application (by doing some typical actions)
- Run LeakDiag to make a first snapshot
- Do some more typical actions
- Run LeakDiag to make a second snapshot
- Run LeakDiag to compare the 2 snapshots and see what caused the additional memory consumption

Possible problem in FireFox might be that FireFox has its own memory manager, not the standard C/C++ run time (at least that's what I think), so you may not find the actual problem this way (as FireFox's memory manager simply hides all exact memory allocations from the system).

**EDIT:** you can do something similar with the GFLAGS and UMDH utilities from Microsoft's Debugging Tools for Windows.